# Is it possible to rename libs to packages in nx?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I want to rename libs folder that nx creates to packages.

Is it something possible [with nx](https://nx.dev/angular/cli/overview)?

Answer (score 33):

You can rename a lib e.g. `nx g @nrwl/workspace:mv --project my-lib --destination their-lib`, more details you can find on [this issue here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2001).

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this, you will need to change the `workspace.json` project's paths that of all the projects that you have into the `libs` folder.

Also, you will need to update the `tsconfig.json` to update the project's resultant path too. Here you will update typescript's references.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the following in your nx.json:

```
 "workspaceLayout": {
    "libs": "packages"
  },
```

[here's how it should look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsdA0.png)